# CSS Selector For Product Price On Page

Tags: javascript, css, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, I'm attempting to store the customers cart subtotal as a variable. I'm having difficulties with accessing the element on the page via css selectors. My desired output would be to store the below subtotal "$254.97" as a float variable --> 254.97

**GTM JavaScript Variable:**

```
function() {
  var priceText = document.querySelector('ENTER_CSS_SELECTOR_HERE');
  var regex = /([0-9.,]+)/;
  if (regex.test(priceText.innerText)) {
    return priceText.innerText.match(regex)[0].replace(/,/g, '');
  }
}
```

**The elements on the page are organized as such:**

```
<div class="grid__item one-half">
                    <p class="cart__subtotal h4"><span class="Bold-theme-hook-DO-NOT-DELETE bold_cart_total" style="display:none !important;"></span><span>$254.97</span></p>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.cart__subtotal span:nth-child(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a normal class selector like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("grid__item")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem. Here are some of them:
First, name your function.

```
function myFunction() {
    var priceText = document.querySelector('.cart__subtotal span:last-child');
    var regex = /([0-9.,]+)/;
    if (regex.test(priceText.innerText)) {
      return priceText.innerText.match(regex)[0].replace(/,/g, '');
    }
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
    var priceText = document.querySelector('.Bold-theme-hook-DO-NOT-DELETE.bold_cart_total + span');
    var regex = /([0-9.,]+)/;
    if (regex.test(priceText.innerText)) {
      return priceText.innerText.match(regex)[0].replace(/,/g, '');
    }
}
```

and `console.log(myFunction());`will display this in the console `254.97`